# Increment buttons not being appended to quantity field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to replicate qty increment and decrement buttons used in my shopping cart onto another page of my website. I have created a jsfiddle that holds all the relevant code, which functions perfectly on the live site, but for reasons I don't understand, it doesn't work on another page, or even in jsfiddle.
The input field html is

```
<div class="shopping_cart_product_qty_wrapper">
<input type="text" name="cart_quantity[]" value="1" size="4" class="cart_input_1698:9fe97fff97f089661135d0487843108e" />
</div>
```

And the relevant script is

```
// Add Increment/Decrement buttons
function add_quantity_buttons(element, vertical) {
    quantity_input = jQuery(element);
    quantity_input.attr('min', '0').attr('inputmode', 'numeric').attr('pattern', '[0-9]*').addClass('inc_dec_quantity_field').wrap('<div class="quantity_field_wrapper clearfix"></div>');

    if (jQuery('.device-xs').is(':visible')) {
        quantity_input.attr('type', 'number');
    } else {
        quantity_input.attr('type', 'text');
    }

    if (jQuery('.device-xs').is(':visible') && vertical !== undefined) {
        quantity_input.after('<a href="#decrease_quantity" class="quantity_dec_button">-</a>').before('<a href="#increase_quantity" class="quantity_inc_button">+</a>');
    } else {
        quantity_input.before('<?php echo ' < span class = "mobile-qty mobile-button-on" > '."Qty:".' < /span>'; ?><a href="#decrease_quantity" class="quantity_dec_button">-</a > ').after(' < a href = "#increase_quantity" class = "quantity_inc_button" > + < /a>');
    }
}

// Handle quantity buttons
// Increment/Decrement button functionality
function increment_decrement_quantity(element, value) {
    $(document.body).on('click', element, function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        quantity = $(this).parent().find(('input'));
        quantity_value = parseInt(quantity.val(), 10);
        quantity_multiple = undefined;

        if (quantity.data('multiple') !== undefined && (quantity.data('multiple') > 0 || quantity.data('multiple') < 0)) {
            quantity_multiple = parseInt(quantity.data('multiple'), 10);
                if (value < 0) {
                    quantity_multiple = quantity_multiple * -1;
                }
            }

            if (quantity_multiple !== undefined && (quantity_multiple > 0 || quantity_multiple < 0)) {
                quantity_value = Math.floor(quantity_value / quantity_multiple) * quantity_multiple;
                value = quantity_multiple;
            } else {
                value = parseInt(value, 10);
            }

            // Validate quantity and increment/decrement value
            if (value > 0 || value < 0 && quantity_value > 0) {
                quantity.val(quantity_value + value).trigger('change');
            }
        });
    }

    // Remove number type and add quantity change buttons
    add_quantity_buttons('#cartContentsDisplay input[name^="cart_quantity"]', true);

    // Decrement button
    increment_decrement_quantity('.quantity_dec_button', -1);

    // Increment button
    increment_decrement_quantity('.quantity_inc_button', +1);

    // Quantity input validation
    var ajax_called = false;
    $(document.body).on('propertychange change click keyup input paste blur', '.inc_dec_quantity_field', function(e) {
        character_code = !e.charCode ? e.which : e.charCode;
        quantity_value = $(this).val();
        leading_zero_plus_regexp = /^(0[0-9]|\+[\+,0-9]).*$/;

        // When input goes out of focus validate quantity value
        if (e.type == 'blur' && (quantity_value == '' || isNaN(quantity_value / 1) == true || isNaN(quantity_value / 1) == false && quantity_value <= 0)) {
            $(this).val('0');
        } else {
            // Check for numeric value and allow backspace, delete, left and right arrows
            if ((isNaN(quantity_value / 1) == false && quantity_value > 0) || (character_code != undefined && (character_code == 39 || character_code == 37 || character_code == 8 || character_code == 46))) {
                // Correct value
                // Make sure the quantity is integer
                if (quantity_value != '' && isNaN(quantity_value / 1) == false && (quantity_value != parseInt(quantity_value, 10) || leading_zero_plus_regexp.test(quantity_value))) {
                    $(this).val(parseInt(quantity_value, 10));
                }
            } else if (character_code != undefined) {
                // Incorrect value
                $(this).val('0');
            } else if (quantity_value != '' && isNaN(quantity_value / 1) == false && (quantity_value != parseInt(quantity_value, 10) || leading_zero_plus_regexp.test(quantity_value))) {
                // Make sure the quantity is integer
                $(this).val(parseInt(quantity_value, 10));
            }
        }
});
```

The fiddle can be found here: https://jsfiddle.net/pv27ue9g/1/

The expected result should give quantity fields like this:
[image]

I stripped all of the js and css out of the page, leaving only what was required to make the increment buttons work before I put together the fiddle, so I'm fairly sure there is nothing missing.

I'm hoping an expert eye on SO will spot the problem as I've been scratching my head over this all day and have got no closer to figuring out why it doesn't function as expected!

Comment: @j08691 Good spot. I wasn't paying enough attention when I set the tags! My apologies

Comment: concatenation here: `.before('<?php echo ' < span class = "mobile-qty mobile-button-on" > '."Qty:".' < /span>'...` is invalid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an issue with the quotes on this line -- you can see in the syntax hilighting

```
   quantity_input.before('<?php echo ' < span class = "mobile-qty mobile-button-on" > '."Qty:".' < /span>'; ?><a href="#decrease_quantity" class="quantity_dec_button">-</a > ').after(' < a href = "#increase_quantity" class = "quantity_inc_button" > + < /a>');
```

Comment: Indeed. jsfiddle can't handle anything in php tags inside the javascript, and for some reason some of the html tags had gained unwanted spaces.

Thanks for pointing that out. I removed the php section and erroneous spaces from the fiddle and it does indeed work now. https://jsfiddle.net/pv27ue9g/2/